# What to do when you need to concatenate a variable with a $_POST value in PHP

Tags: php, post, http-post, concatenation, backend

On front-end i have a hidden dynamic input which has a dynamic atribute `name` as well

the html `echo '<input type="hidden" name="like_c_'.$pc.'" value="like" />';`
the php variable is concatenated inside  attritute 
in html would be like

```
<input type="hidden" name="like_c_abcde123.'" value="like" />
```

**name="like_c_**`'.$pc.'`"

just to make it easier to understand the code above, html is in bold and php in pre code format

on my php backend I need to get this:

```
   $string = htmlentities($_POST['like_c']);//concatenate variable here
```

the question is how to concatenate to get the exact `$_POST` name 
like this: **name="like_c_**`'.$pc.'`"

my code is sent via `jquery serialize` also  is dinamic generated, with db value on frontend,  that's why i need the concatenation on the backend

I don't know if this would be the right way

```
$string = htmlentities($_POST['like_c_'.$var]);
```

The problem here is that I think it would not work since `like_c_`would be treated as `name="like_c_"`

Comment: Can you give sample of two or three dynamic generated variables? Maybe there is a pattern that can be used.

Comment: `echo '<input type="hidden" name="like_c_'.$pc.'" value="like" />';` in html would be like `<input type="hidden" name="like_c_abcde123.'" value="like" />`

Comment: It's just one sample. You can solve it easily if they form any pattern.

Comment: the  variable output a random value of 10 digits with pattern like `abcde123` letters and numbers

Comment: Do you store these random values? If not how would you concatenate? If you don't know the exact name of the variable, you can walk through all $_POST array.
If you store them then simplly `$var = "like_c$pc"; $_POST[$var];`

Comment: I do store those random values on database, it's not a problem to find the value at all, I just need to concatenate with the `$_POST`

Comment: something like `$string = htmlentities($_POST['like_c_'.$var]);`

Comment: the problem here is that I think it would not work since `like_c_`would be treated as `name="like_c_"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might works for you.

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, 'like_c_') === 0) {
       $key = htmlentities($_POST[$key]);
    }
}
```